# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. MYSQL work bench?

Tags: mysql, php, mysql-workbench

I have created php and Mysql site.Its Working Locally Xampp well. Finally I moved My site to server..i have Used Mysql Workbench. connected client database in Mysql Workbench in My system.when I Run the code its showing Error:

```
Validating Information....error with query: 
SELECT ID,fname,lname,email,userlevel,user_group,orgID 
FROM students 
WHERE username='test' 
AND password='123456' 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Comment: The first you need to do is edit your question because I can't understand all what you asking for. There's a post like this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736396/mysql-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it

Comment: does telnet to db machine with db port from source machine get succeeded?

Answer (score 1):

You should check mysql user permission, specially the host field.
[Mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html)